# How to use Kruskal-Wallis test to compare different group in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like below:

[image: dataframe]

I want to use Kruskal-Wallis test to compare compound 1 in group A, B, C, D's concentration.
For example, compound 1, group A with group B,  compare their concentration.
The comparison should be made between different group within same compound.
Group comparison should be as below.

[image]

I tried the code like below

```
# Performing Kruskal-Wallis test
kruskal.test(Group~Concentration, data = df) )
```

But it use all Group A data (include compound1, compound2, ...).
I want to compare within one compound, how to change the code?

Comment: See [Is there a nonparametric equivalent of Tukey HSD?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17342/is-there-a-nonparametric-equivalent-of-tukey-hsd).

Comment: The  internet search term "r Kruskal-Wallis" has loads of results; what have you tried and what are your coding problems:  [Helpful guidance for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Peter, I added it now, thanks for reminder.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide sample data using `dput` or similar, I made up a data frame with sample data.

You can run the Kruskal-Wallis-Test in R with the function `kruskal.test`

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(group = sample(x = LETTERS[1:4], size = 20, replace = T),
                 compound = rep(1:4, 5),
                 concentration = rnorm(20, mean = 0.4, sd = 0.2))


kruskal.test(concentration ~ group, data = df)
```

The result is

```
> kruskal.test(concentration ~ group, data = df)

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  concentration by group
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 0.5648, df = 3, p-value = 0.9044
```

Also, check out `?kruskal.test` for the function documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this code set for certain compound? What confused me most is that I need to set within certain compound, compare groups with concentration. Is this code could solve this ? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: All you've shown is how to perform a Kruskal-Wallis test, which is trivial. OP is asking to perform many such tests for each possible combination pair. There are better ways of doing this then manually going through each.